# PHP: 500 Server Error - Request for access token for Microsoft Azure Active Directory Access

Tags: php, azure, post, active-directory

I'm following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

I have just completed this step (by simply visiting the URL below):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code
```

Which redirected me to my redirect URL with code query string attached:

```
https://example.com/?code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCm.................................
```

At the end of the `code` query string above, there was an additional `session_state` parameter.

The next step outlined in the link at the top of this question says to make a `POST` request, but I'm having trouble forming this call.

Here's what the docs represent being an example:

[image: Authorization code to request an access token example]

**How would I form and call this request in PHP (without using `cURL`)?**

Here's my attempt, but I don't know whether or not I'm correct:

```
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oath2/token';

$data = array( 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
               'client_id' => '2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e',
               'code' => 'AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCm...................',
               'redirect_uri' => 'https://example.com',
               'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
               'client_secret' => '{client_secret}' );

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$var_dump($result);
```

**UPDATE:** The code above (when executed) returns a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Also, I don't know whether or not I should be adding `session_state` (mentioned above) into the `POST` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token`.

You have to add the client secret to the request, as well as the resource.

If you are trying to call Microsoft Graph for example, the resource should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Comment: Where would I be able to obtain the `client_secret`?

Comment: After you register the app in Azure AD, there should be a button for Keys. Create one there, those are client secrets. It's essentially a password that your app uses to prove its identity to AAD.

Comment: I updated the code, but when I try to make the request, it returns a `500` error.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say why that would happen. Anything in the response from Azure AD?

Comment: The only thing I'm seeing with relation to the response headers is `Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate`. Otherwise, where could I check more details errors about AD?

Comment: The response body can have some details. Though sometimes it just says "Something went wrong".

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no response body.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with PHP, but this sample should probably help you: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web. It uses client credentials authentication whereas yours is doing authorization code authentication. But the process is very similar when it comes to retrieving an access token.

Comment: I'll take a look, but one last question. I've got an Apache server hosting this code (not tied to Azure), which is calling this request, are you sure all the above parameters are what they should be?

Comment: They seem to be correct. Assuming you replace {tenant} with your actual tenant id or domain name, e.g. mytenant.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: Yes, have already replaced. Is there a place in `portal.azure` I can check if there are any errors associated with the AD calls?

Comment: No, not really :/ Best option is to try to do the call manually with Fiddler/Postman, and see if there is something wrong with the parameters.

Comment: Wait, Am I supposed to be incorporating `session_state` into anything?

Comment: I don't think so. But you could try adding the value to the request as well.